# Java 8 Streams - Filter More Than One Condition

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Based on some sports results data, I have a `Fixture` object which has `getHome()` and `getAway()` method. I'd like to shorten this method which I've written to only use a single lambda function (instead of creating a new list and two lambdas), is this possible?

```
    private Collection<FixtureResult> finalResults(Team team) {

    List<FixtureResult>finalResults = new ArrayList<>();

    List<FixtureResult> homeResults = resultList.stream().filter(fixture ->
            fixture.getHome().equals(team))
            .collect(toList());

    List<FixtureResult> awayResults = resultList.stream().filter(fixture ->
            fixture.getAway().equals(team))
            .collect(toList());

    finalResults.addAll(homeResults);
    finalResults.addAll(awayResults);

    return finalResults;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple enough

```
resultList.stream()
        .filter(fixture -> fixture.getHome().equals(team) || fixture.getAway().equals(team)))
        .collect(toList());
```

**EDIT:** This is on the assumption that order does not matter to you. If your final list needs to have home result and then away, have a look at [Elliott Frisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49368438/4405757).

Answer (score 15):

If you wan to get fancy with lambdas:

```
Predicate<FixtureResult> isHome = fr -> fr.getHome().equals(team)
Predicate<FixtureResult> isAway = fr -> fr.getAway().equals(team)

resultList.stream()
  .filter(isHome.or(isAway))
  .collect(toList()));
```

You could even extract the compose predicate to test it in isolation, with no streams involved, which is good for more complex predicates:

```
Predicate<FixtureResult> isHomeOrAway = isHome.or(isAway)

assertTrue(isHomeOrAway(homeFixture)); 
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the order doesn't matter, you can do it on one line. Like,

```
private Collection<FixtureResult> finalResults(Team team) {
    return resultList.stream()
            .filter(fixture -> fixture.getHome().equals(team) 
                    || fixture.getAway().equals(team))
            .collect(toList());
}
```

If the order matters (home results and then away), you can do it with a single `List` like

```
private Collection<FixtureResult> finalResults(Team team) {
    List<FixtureResult> al = new ArrayList<>(resultList.stream()
            .filter(fixture -> fixture.getHome().equals(team)).collect(toList()));
    al.addAll(resultList.stream()
            .filter(fixture -> fixture.getAway().equals(team)).collect(toList()));
    return al;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following

```
someStream.filter(((Predicate<SomeClass>) someObject-> someCondition).or(someObject-> someOtherCondition))
```

Or you can define your own "or" function that won't cause such a deep hierarchy

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<R> Predicate<R> or(Predicate<R> ...predicates) {
   return r -> Arrays.stream(predicates).anyMatch(p -> p.test(r));
}
```

That gives you a cleaner interface without casting and the nesting

```
.filter(or(
      yourObject -> {
          return false;
      },
      yourObject -> {
          return false;
      },
      yourObject -> {
          return false;
      },
      yourObject -> {
          return false;
      }
 ))
```

Comment: This is a gem hidden at bottom of the page! Hopefully more developers realise the elegance of these types of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a conditions concatenations or can concatenate multiple **filter** call

**Conditions concatenations**

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(element -> (condition1 && condition2 && condition3))
```

**Multiple filter call**

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(element -> condition1)
      .filter(element -> condition2)
      .filter(element -> condition3)
```

Comment: Each next filter call applies to filtered results. The author most probably wanted OR filter conditions.