# Parallelising Java 8 parallelStream independent filters

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-stream, parallelstream

I read all the related topics on StackOverflow and other sites to understand the mechanism of the `parallelStream` of Java8, and to understand whether the applied filters are running concurrently or not.
**Are they running in a parallel way without waiting for each other or not?**
Does it happen only when you have separated filters or not?

**I read:**

[Java 8 Streams: multiple filters vs. complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054773/java-8-streams-multiple-filters-vs-complex-condition)

[Java 8 Streams - Filter More Than One Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368308/java-8-streams-filter-more-than-one-condition)

[JavaScript: multiple filters chain vs. complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65665221/javascript-multiple-filters-chain-vs-complex-condition)

[Parallelising Java 8 Stream.filter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450750/parallelising-java-8-stream-filter)

[Filter and foreach java 8 stream as parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940888/filter-and-foreach-java-8-stream-as-parallel)

I could not find a simple answer to this simple question.

I did find answers about the performance differences and other things that related to the question whether to choose only one filter with a complex condition or multiple filters with one simple condition.

But this is not what I am trying to find out.

My question is:
When I write something like:

```
Optional<List<Pokemon>> filteredPokemons = getPokemonsList()
            .map(pokemons -> pokemons.parallelStream() //parallel filter for each pokemon
                    .filter(pokemon -> isRed(pokemon.getColor()) && isAmazing(pokemon) && !pokemonAlreadyActivated(pokemon))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

What is really happening , filter wise?
Is the first condition in the filter, `isRed(..)`, gets checked first and if it returns false, it doesn't proceed to check the rest of the conditions?

What will happen if I'll split this one filter into 3 different filters:

```
Optional<List<Pokemon>> filteredPokemons = getPokemonsList()
    .map(pokemons -> pokemons.parallelStream()
            .filter(pokemon -> isRed(pokemon.getColor()))
            .filter(pokemon -> isAmazing(pokemon))
            .filter(pokemon -> !pokemonAlreadyActivated(pokemon))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I know that performance wise, the first option, with only one filter and complex condition is preferred (reference: [Java 8 Streams: multiple filters vs. complex condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054773/java-8-streams-multiple-filters-vs-complex-condition)).

But what about concurrency?
Because logically, it is seems like in the second option, with split filters, they can run in a parallel way without waiting for each other, so it should be faster and better, so how does the first option is still considered better?

Doesn't the first option makes the conditions wait for each other to be checked, unlike the separated filters which can run in a concurrent and parallel way without the need to depend on each other.

I'll be glad to understand the difference and to understand if separated filters are running concurrently unlike one filter with several conditions in it.

Comment: What's that `map` doing in there? You just mean `getPokemonsList().parallelStream()` right?

Comment: Each *element* will pass through the filters sequentially. But multiple elements can be processed in parallel.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for noticing. I actually meant the returned list to be `Optional`. I have fixed it. thanks again.

Comment: @Jorn I agree and this is the point of `parallelStream()` of Java8. But my question is not about the concurrent processing of the element, it's about the concurrent processing of the filters applied to each element.

Comment: @NoobCoder I addressed that already. The filters won't be applied to separate elements in parallel.

Comment: @Jorn again, I can't fully understand your answer. I don't want the filters to be applied to seperated elements in parallel, I want to know if they are applied to *one* element in parallel. Let me be more clear: `parallelStream()` handles elements in a concurrent way, and each element needs to check the same filters. Lets say you have 3 filters like here in my above example. Will they run in parallel or not? even if they have seperated `.filter(..)` they won't run in parallel way? So there is no difference between one filter to seperated ones? either way they will wait for the previous?

Comment: "either way they will wait for the previous?" Yes. You misunderstood parallel streams if you were expecting something else.

Comment: For the third time: *you cannot do that with `parallelStream`*. If you want to do it, you need to write an async function that starts to run each filter, but short-circuits as soon as one of them returns `false`. It's not impossible, but it's unlikely to perform better than just running the checks sequentially.

Comment: You should never use “optional lists”. In most cases, the absent list is equivalent to an empty list and can be handled as such. But even if you insist on using optional lists, you should not distract the readers of your question with these irrelevant details. Just post the stream operation your question is about.

Comment: The 3 filters could be run on different threads but are sequental for each specific element in the stream. If the evaluation on "x" of the first filter isRed is false, the stream no longer contains "x" and so the filter evaluation isAmazing(x) won't occur.

Comment: @DuncG Thanks for the explanation. So, as I understand, there is only one evaluation of "x" each time, not matter if it's in one complex filter or several separated simple filters. There is only one "x" evaluation at a time, and if it fails, it won't proceed to the next evaluation whether if it's a condition or a whole other filter. so `is.Red(x) && is.Amazing(x)` equal to `.filter(isRed(x)) .filter(isAmazing(x))` by that that in both cases it will evaluate `x` by one condition at a time even if there are few threads.

Comment: @Holger it's a little bit off topic, but it's interesting. What if `Optional` is the type that required by the caller? The called method has to return an optional, whether if it's a list or not.

Comment: That would be the first time in programming history that the caller can dictate what a method or function returns. If caller and callee disagree about the return type, every compiler in this world will tell you that the caller is wrong and needs to be adapted. But regardless of that, the logic of an “optional list” is flawed, regardless of where you introduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```java
stringList.parallelStream()
    .filter(string -> string != null)
    .filter(string -> !string.isEmpty())
    …
```

This example is semantically equivalent to

```java
stringList.parallelStream()
    .filter(string -> string != null && !string.isEmpty())
    …
```

and it should be clear that we have to obey the semantic of `&&`, as we can’t evaluate the second condition before we know whether the first condition is fulfilled, as otherwise, the code would break.

Since the Stream implementation doesn’t know what the condition evaluation will do and whether they depend on each other like shown in the example, as all it gets is an opaque `Predicate` implementation, it has to assume that there could be such a dependency. So, the evaluation of the predicates can not be done in parallel for one element.

In theory, the second `filter` stage could process an element which passed the filter while the first `filter` stage processes the next element, but as said in [the answer you already linked yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24055107/2711488), this road has not been taken.

As far as I know, there were experiments in that direction in early development phases, which led to the conclusion that the overhead is too high.

Instead, the workload is split at the source, like splitting the list into sublists, and the parts are processed sequentially, passing each element through the pipeline in a fused operation. This per-element operation requires no thread synchronization in the best case and is JIT friendly.

Comment: Got it! So in conclusion, the `.filter` util of java `stream` or `parallelStream` acts like a pipeline, which forces the each filter to wait till the previous one will be evaluated and done. And each filter will run only if the previous one has successfully passed and not filtered. 
Exactly like a complex condition where you have few conditions connected with an arithmetic `AND` operation `"&&"`, which run only one condition by order. So as you said, by this logic, both "`.filter(condition & condition)`" and "`.filter(condition) .filter(condition)` are not checking the conditions parallelly.